# freeware which can create windows to embed other applications?

Tags: windows

There was such a software I met in the past I don't remember the name, do you know some ?

I remembered you could put applications in splitted window as if you had a composite applications into one.

Comment: What? Can you elaborate on what you exactly want?

Comment: Hi see above and below

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague, but were you possibly thinking of the [Window Dock](http://www.anappaday.com/downloads/2006/10/day-22-jedi-window-dock.html) from the old 'An App A Day' challenge?

There's a much better application (but the free version is limited to 3 tabs per group) which does the same thing called [WindowTabs](http://www.windowtabs.com/download/).

Comment: Great thanks, they seem great. Though what I remembered from the old one was not only to put in tabs but in splitted window as if you had a composite applications in one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a tiling window manager, like this one?

[WinSplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/)

See also [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asuperuser.com+tiling+window+manager) for more information regarding those window managers.

Comment: Hi thanks, almost, I would just like that the windows could be embedded in another window as if they were components.